# How do I give a default value to a map?

Tags: c++

I have an map that takes a string and it returns a integer. I want the integer of the map instance to be initialized to 0. How would I do that? For example:

```
std::map<std::string, int> x;
```

I want all the integers to be intialized to 0 as their starting point. How do I do this?

Comment: They are implicitly 0. When you access a key which hasn't been inserted before, it's initialized with 0. So, for example `x[someKey]++` will store `1` at the specified key if it didn't exist before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply accessing a certain key will default-initialize its corresponding value. For `int`, that is equivalent to setting it to 0:

```
x["foo"];
```

Although, to be honest, it'd be easier to read as `x["foo"] = 0;`.

Comment: The thing is I don't know what `foo` is. It is entered in by the user.  But I guess this solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @MemyselfandI If you don't know what the keys are, your map doesn't have any values in it. Values are associated with keys. If there are N keys, there are N values.

Comment: Doesn't it value-initialize the value? It inserts `T()`. As far as I can recall, a default-initialized int is uninitialized, such as here: `struct S {int i;} s; //s.i=?`